# How to get stock datas from finance.yahoo?

Tags: c#, httprequest, yahoo, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I need to get all the stock data from Yahoo Finance api. but considering the security level of this  table I can not realize it with the  help of  http requests.

**Level 1**

I've found the list of finance tables from YDL [YDL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) with command  "**Show Tables**" and get the results:

```
<table security="APP">pm.finance</table>
<table security="APP">pm.finance.articles</table>
<table security="APP">pm.finance.autocomplete</table>
<table security="APP">pm.finance.graphs</table>
<table security="APP">pm.finance.markettickers</table>
```

**Level 2**

When  I try  this command "**desc pm.finance**" I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2017-12-13T13:24:57Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
  <results>
    <table hash="a8196c4d279e0e28fb671a81b9a40bd3" name="pm.finance" security="APP">
      <meta>
      <sampleQuery>
        select * from pm.finance where symbol="YHOO"
      </sampleQuery>
      </meta>
      <request>
        <select>
                    <key name="symbol" required="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </select>
      </request>
    </table>
  </results>
</query>
```

**Level 3** 
When I tried to use the sample query `select * from pm.finance where symbol="YHOO"` I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<description>Authentication Error.  The table pm.finance requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least APP is expected</description>
```

I need  to realize  the  implementation  in http request  level . Using  C# HttpWebrequest or HttpClient. YDL quides from  [datatables.com](https://www.datatables.org/) are  inactive. I don't know how to use  it.

Comment: well the error tells you exactly what's wrong, `you don't have the proper security level`

Comment: i  know what  it means  . I also have create YDN  app . But  don't know how to use  in http requests  level  .

Comment: Have you tried changing your URL to https?

Comment: Is the request getting cached? I can see you're using `security=app`, while the error still assumes you're using `security=any`.

Comment: Yes  , I've crated the  YDN app  for this .  As I understand in order to use  api with "app" security  level I have to authorize  with  OAuth . But I don't know how to realize all this with  http requests .

Comment: Please do not add unnecessary edits to "bump" this question. If you find that people are not answering, add new information to it from your ongoing research and investigations.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You should keep in mind that Yahoo finance is depreciated. ( https://github.com/wilsonfreitas/awesome-quant/issues/26 )

Comment: I have found  alternative solution .  
1 > send get request  with  random number  for taking cookie https://finance.yahoo.com/?2e4e0231 
2> Set cookie  and send get request 
 https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb 
3> Set cookie and  crumb  ,  and send GEt request for example like that : 
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=1506830400&period2=1512104400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=Yoi8hM44eBf